# Trendnet TEW-664UB Not recognized in Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, drivers, adapter

I just installed a Ubuntu system on my computer and its not working with my TrendNet TEW 664-UB (the device works fine in Windows 7). At first I thought this was a driver issue so I tried `ndiswrapper`, however, when I type in `lsusb` in terminal it doesn't show a Trendnet USB, it only shows the keyboard and mouse attached to it. So what can I do to get my wireless adapter working on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the wireless card to work using the new `rt8192cu` driver created by Larry Finger:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192du.git
cd rtl8192du
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192du
```

Every time you upgrade the kernel, run these commands again:

```
cd rtl8192du
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192du
```

Source: [The Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2153777)